# Where is usually located the Python Interpreter on Android devices?

Tags: file-management, python

I have installed qpython. Just don't know what exactly is an interpreter neither where should i look for it on Android devices. Thanks

Comment: Android doesn't have Python pre-installed, that's why you need to install third party app. Now it depends on the app where it keeps it's files. Interpreter must be somewhere in `/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/` directory.

Comment: I believe i found one interpreter on termux: /data/data/com.termux/files/bin/env thanks

Comment: But that's a different app, won't work with QPython.

Comment: I'll try /data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/bin/qpython3-android5 and will update the answer